# Any transformation of Gaussian random variables admits covariance calculation after transformation?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, logit

Sigmoid transform of Gaussian random variables does not have an easy calculation of covariance.

Specifically, I'm looking for a function transform $$f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0, 1]$$
such that it can transform a Gaussian variable to a probability.

I have two Gaussian random variables $(x_1, x_2)$ with non-zero correlation. After transformation, I want to calculate the correlation of $(f(x_1), f(x_2))$.

UPDATE: I'm fitting a model $f(Gaussian(\mu, \Sigma))$ on some data. After I do model fitting and obtain $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, I need to calculate the covariance of my model, so I need to calculate $cov(f(x_1), f(x_2))$. The function $f$ satisfies the modeling need as long as it has a shape like the sigmoid function. But covariance calculation requires a special form of $f$.

Any hints?

Comment: 1. logit is log(p/(1-p)). That's not going to make sense on a normal; you probably mean the antilogit exp(x)/(1+exp(x)]  ... 2. to what end? What's the ultimate aim? Are approximations okay?

Comment: Yes, I mean antilogit or sigmoid. The ultimate goal is the calculation of the covariance of $(f(x_1), f(x_2))$.

Comment: You said that in your post already -- but if the transformation $f$ is essentially any arbitrary cdf (also as in your post), *what purpose does that serve*?? What's the point in having the covariance between arbitrarily transformed variates?

Comment: Perhaps defining a copula might solve your problem? Are you specifically looking for a closed form solution for the covariance? As Glen_b pointed out, it doesn't make sense to find the covariance of $(f_1, f_2)$ after applying _any_ arbitrary transformation $f$. Perhaps what you could do is to apply the appropriate marginal CDFs to transform $$ (\Phi_1(x_1), \Phi_2(x_2)) \mapsto (u_1, u_2) $$. You'd then be able to calculate some measure of correlation like the pearson or the kendall tau

Comment: The answer to this question seems to hinge on what you mean by "easy calculation:" could you elaborate?  The very easiest calculation I can imagine is one that does not have to be done at all.  For instance, the transformation $f(x)=1/2$ will work.

Comment: Thank you all! Just post an update. @whuber: I'm looking for closed-form solutions.

Comment: @Aditya Ravuri: do I have closed-form solutions when I calculate the statistics you are mentioning? I have a large problem (many more than two in the example), so I want a closed-form solution.

Comment: No, the normal cdf doesn't have an analytical expression. This exercise seems a bit convoluted, even slightly different-looking sigmoid-like functions can enforce very different behavior. Even if you do find a function, be careful with how you use it. E.g. a "quickly varying" sigmoid (one with a massive slope when it curves up) would basically make a lot of your variables go to 0 or 1, and the concept of correlation might not even make sense when applied to such a dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought, I think I find a solution:

The transformation can be:

$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}  \frac{1}{2}\exp(x) & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \\ 1 - \frac{1}{2} \exp(-x) & \mbox{if } x >0 \end{array} \right.$

One can take the expectation of $f(x_1) \cdot f(x_2)$ with respect to a bi-variate Gaussian distribution of $(x_1, x_2)$.